# Do I need UK transit visa to move from Terminal 2 to Terminal 3 Heathrow?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, lhr, ireland

I (Indian) have a travel itinerary from Dublin to India via UK Heathrow airport. From the airline website, it says that I need to move from Terminal 2 to Terminal 3 of Heathrow airport. As I have never been to Heathrow before, do I need to pass the border check/immigration? If so then do I need to have UK transit visa or some sort? I'm a work visa holder in Ireland. Please help me with this guys. Thanks!

Comment: This https://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections might help

Answer (score 1):

You **do not** need a Transit visa if:

> You have an **Indian** passport; and
>
> you arrive and depart by air have a confirmed onward flight that
> **leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you
> arrive** have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for
> that country); and
>
> you’re traveling from the Republic of Ireland and it’s less than 3 months since you were last given permission, on the basis of **holding a valid Irish biometric visa**, to land or be in Ireland

(GOV Website)

If you do not meet **all** of these requirements, you will need to apply for a Visitor in Transit Visa.